# Jquery Datepicker - Calculate End Date, based on start date and drop down list of number of weeks

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I would like to know if this is possible to calculate an end date based on user picking a start date and a select list of number of weeks.

i.e.  I select a course for 2 weeks, and choose a start date of 10th Feb - in theory the date field would automatically update with the date that is two weeks later, i.e. 24th February.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could do something like:

```
$('#start-date').bind('blur', function() {
   var days = $('#weeks-select').val() * 7;
   var endDate = new Date($(this).val());
   endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + days);
   $('#end-date').val( (endDate.getMonth() + 1)+ '/' + endDate.getDate() + '/' + endDate.getFullYear() );
});
```

where:

- `#weeks-select` is the dropdown with the number of weeks
- `#start-date` is the start date input
- `#end-date` is the end date input

Modified it to match your order of operations. ie. User picks a number of weeks and then a start date.

Comment: I think `blur` is not the right event for this situation. Is `change` not good? ;)

Comment: `change` is good, but `blur` is better ;). I figured you would want it to change once it loses focus, but change works too.

Comment: Yeah. And I bet it will still calculate things even when it should not. I mean, if you click it, it gains focus, and, even if you are not changing the value "un-focusing" would still do its calculation.

Comment: Thankyou Victor. Will try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could. It's just a matter of `Date` manipulation in javascript.
Have you tried asking [google](http://www.google.com)?

here's one http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut19.htm

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy with jQuery's Datepicket plugin:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: Thanks sokratissg, will try all three approaches.